# How to project additional data from an aggregate result with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm learning MongoDB and try to group a collection.
What I'm looking for is to group by year, get the max "average note" field and display the field primary name of the document related to this average

For example, if I have:

```
Name    | Average   | Year
Name_01 | 7.56      | 1995
Name_02 | 8.96      | 1995
Name_03 | 3.25      | 2005
Name_04 | 4.36      | 2005
Name_05 | 7.52      | 2020
```

I need:

```
Name    | Average   | Year
Name_02 | 8.96      | 1995
Name_05 | 7.52      | 2020
Name_04 | 4.36      | 2005
```

I already did the group and the max. Here is my code:

```
db.foobar.aggregate([
    {
        $group: { _id: '$year_published', max: { $max: '$statistics.average' }}
    },
    {
        $project: { _id: 1, max: 1 }
    }, 
    {
        $sort: { max: -1 }
    }    
])
```

Which gives me this kind of result:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1999,
            "max" : 8.0343000000000000
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 1985,
            "max" : 7.8833299999999999
        }
        // An so on...
}
```

But I'd also like to project the primary name of the document related to the "max" to get something like:

```
 {
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1999,
            "max" : 8.0343000000000000,
            "name": "Foo Bar"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 1985,
            "max" : 7.8833299999999999,
            "name": "Lorem Ipsum"
        }
        // An so on...
}
```

*NB : The next part of the question add complexity regarding the name (because of my document structure). It's not my main concern right now, but I add it to the question to reflect all my problem.*

The primary name is a bit tricky to get. For each document, I've got an array of objects like that:

```
{
    "names" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "primary",
            "value" : "Foo bar"
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "alternate",
            "value" : "Foo foo"
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "alternate",
            "value" : "Bar bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

And what I'm trying to get is the name with "primary" type (i. e. "Foo bar" in my example).

Here is the structure of my documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56338f2bdc99b8ec22a43328"),
    "names" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "primary",
            "value" : "Foo bar"
        },
        {
            "type" : "alternate",
            "value" : "Barr foo"
        }
    ],
    "year_published" : 1992
    "statistics" : {
        "average" : 6.6057699999999997
    }
}
```

I think I'm not so far but I don't know how to do it... Could you please help me?

Comment: If you want help you need to show the data you originally have and what you need to get from it. Otherwise it's just a guess.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I added an example at the begging and also the structure of my documents.

Comment: @user3100115 I disagree since this is not a single point lesson, and there are other parts to the problem. Pointing to the duplicate of of part does not solve the other part.

Comment: @BlakesSeven good point.

Comment: @user3100115 My pointer ( and personal preference ), if I see a question that is not completely "clear" I mark it as such for a close. This I deem to be largely a protection of the OP asking, as unclear questions mostly receive answers ( mostly bad and incorrect ) anyway. So also a comment is left for clarification points, and the onus is put on the OP to make their point clear. If they do ( at any point ) then I retract/vote to re-open as the OP has made their point. The same applies to "parital" duplicates, or the OP not understanding a marked duplicate. Protection and resolution is the goal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the "paried" values out of a particular doccument with a "max" value then `$max` is not for you. Instead what you need to do is [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) the data first and then use the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator.

```js
db.foobar.aggregate([
    { "$sort":  { "year_published": 1, "statistics.average": -1 } },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$year_published", 
        "max": { "$first": "$statistics.average" }},
        "name": { 
            "$first": {
                "$setDifference": [
                    { "$map": {
                        "input": "$names",
                        "as": "name",
                        "in": {
                            "$cond": {
                                "if": { "$eq": [ "$$name.type", "primary" ] },
                                "then": "$$name.value",
                                "else": false
                            }
                        }
                    }},
                    [false]
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$name" }
])
```

The `$first` and `$last` operators act on "grouping boundary" data. Which means they return data from the property that occurs either at the begining or end of the value that was used for the grouping `_id`.

That is why you "sort" first, so th documents are in order for selection.

By contrast `$max` and `$min` just pick the "max/min" value from anywhere in the documents in the sample. That's fine when it's all you want, but if you want "related" fields, then you **must** sort first.

That's the basics of it. The other part for dealing with filtering your array is most optimally done with the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) combination as shown. The `$map` allows testing of a condition via [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) on each array element "in-line", and returns the value depending on which is true or false. The result is still of course an array of equal length.

The `$setDifference` essentially filters out anything returned as `false`, so the only thing left should be the "primary". Still an array, which is why `$unwind` is still used, though it's only a single element array.

Future MongoDB versions will do this a little better with `$filter` and `$arrayElemAt`. Here's a glimpse:

```js
db.foobar.aggregate([
    { "$sort":  { "year_published": 1, "statistics.average": -1 } },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$year_published", 
        "max": { "$first": "$statistics.average" }},
        "name": { 
            "$first": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                    { "$filter": {
                        "input": "$names",
                        "as": "name",
                        "cond": {
                            "$eq": [ "$$name.type", "primary" ]
                        }
                    }},
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

But none of this changes the basic rules of "sort first" and then just pick up the values from the grouping boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code :
You need to select the "name" filed in the group pipeline operation with the help of [$First](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/).

[$First](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) selects the value that results from applying an expression to the first document in a group of documents that share the same group by key.

```
db.foobar.aggregate([ 
{ "$unwind" : "$names" },
{ $match :
           { "$names.type" : "primary"}
} ,
{ $sort : 
          { "year_published" : 1, "statistics.average" : -1 } 
},
{ $group : 
          { _id :  "$year_published" , 
            name : {
                     $first : "$names.value" 
                   }, 
            max: { $max: "$statistics.average" } 
          }
},
{ $sort: 
        { max: -1 } 
}  
]).pretty();
```

This will give you the required result :

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1999,
            "max" : 8.0343000000000000,
            "name": "Foo Bar"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 1985,
            "max" : 7.8833299999999999,
            "name": "Lorem Ipsum"
        }
        // An so on...
}
```

Comment: Well, I tried it but it's not the right name. I think it's the first name for the year (i. e. _id) but not the name with the max '$statistics.average'.